# ReactJS State and XAML VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, silverlight, reactjs, visualstatemanager

Is the purpose behind [ReactJS state management](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and XAML [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx) the same to achieve the visual state management for a UI component? Does it make easy to think ReactJS state management similar to XAML VisualStateManager if someone come from a WPF or Silverlight background?

Comment: I'd never looked at ReactJS before, but after skimming that link you gave I don't think I want to again. I'd take a XAML VSM over that any day, or at least Angular and css3. On that note, I think this is one of those questions that may end up leading to primarily opinion based answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice [article](http://nikcodes.com/2015/03/16/something-razor-should-learn-from-jsx/) comparing ReactJS components to ASP.NET Razor template controls. The patterns in [XAML custom controls](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c85cf/custom-control-classes-and-dependency-properties-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7/) and ReactJS seems similar, but not Visual State Manager.